# Unable to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 due to Error

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

Have tried several times to upgrade to from 20.04 to 22.04 by following

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But every time it fails at this very same spot with the message:

Here are the errors I get:

[Code snippet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bjmLgvwydcJjVvOeLoFrFlrwP0xnL4f8oVVwmVe5Mss/edit?usp=sharing)

Used this guide:
[How to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-22-04-lts/)

Comment: It's right there in your own screenshot, cut off on the top edge: An error among your sources. Fix that. Next time, copy-and-paste the text into your question instead of using screenshots.

Comment: I have noticed it , too, and tried to fix the missing keys with   Y PPA manager but it did not help

Comment: Tried to fix the missing keys with YPPA manager but it didn't help. Here is code I get https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bjmLgvwydcJjVvOeLoFrFlrwP0xnL4f8oVVwmVe5Mss/edit?usp=sharing I see signal.org is reoccurring error but I removed Signal.... @user535733

Comment: Used sudo apt-get purge signal-desktop to removed Signal

Comment: @gd bros gd  - I have wired connection it works perfectly

Comment: I mainly had two GPG Errors one with https://repo.skype.com/deb and the other with GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb USED At the terminal command line find the apt sources file that refers to the signal repo:
sudo grep -l signal.org /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* and then sudo /bin/rm -v to remove the signal and skype repos

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS because of GPG Keys errors of two 2 previously removed packages. In my case they were were **Skype** and **Signal**. The problem was that Signal and Skype repository won't go away regardless of what I tried to remove them. I removed Signal and Skype via the package manager/software center but they somehow continued to remain. I also used Y PPA Manager but it did not help. The errors were similar to this:

```
Err https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D980A17457F6FB06
```

So at the terminal command line I found the apt source files that refer to the Signal and the Skype repositories:

```
sudo grep -l signal.org /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

After executing the code you get all the source files paths so I manually removed each source file. To remove it I used the following code line where in the quotation marks you have to copy
and paste the source files path similarly to the example below without the quotation marks:

```
sudo /bin/rm -v "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signalrepofile.list"
```

This will remove the source files. Then Run

```
$ sudo apt update
```

And they were gone...

Only after the errors were gone my upgrade proceeded by using these steps

[How to Upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the given answer, also see that you remove the ***cloudflare warp-cli*** or maybe any other VPN profile that you have installed.
Also make sure that there are no GPG key error if you run

```
sudo apt update
```

Remove every header that is giving the GPG key error from

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

as mentioned in the first answer.

Doing the above fixed the problem for me. Hope it helps you too.